# How to add counter in angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular, html, typescript, angular6

I have a function which grabs comments from the server, I would like to display total number of comments available in a server.

Here is the function in .ts file:

```
 this.activeRouter.params.subscribe(params => {
   // tslint:disable-next-line:prefer-const
   let id = params['id'];
   this.userService.getComments(id)
     .pipe(
       map(data => data.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.localTime).getTime() - new Date(a.localTime).getTime()))
      )
      .subscribe(data => this.comments = data);
});
```

Here is the get function in service

```
  getComments (id: number) {
    return this.http.get<Comment[]>(this.commentsUrl);
  }
```

Here is the html for displaying comments

```
 <div class="comments-description" *ngFor="let comment of comments">
        <span class="comments_count">(353)</span>
      <div class="comments-photo">
        <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/84.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="comments_wrapper">
        <div class="comments_details">
          <h1>{{comment.author}}</h1>
          <span class="days">1d</span>
        </div>
        <div class="comments_text">
          <p>{{comment.description}} </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not simply use the length

```
<span class="comments_count">{{comments.length}}</span>
```

Comment: such solution indicates only comments, that were got, not 'total number of comments available in a server'

Comment: @user9964622 Cool.. make sure to check as answer if this helped :)

Comment: No problem stack needs me to wait a minute to accept :P here is my other thread am strugling on formating dates , u can check it if u dont mind , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033868/how-to-format-dates-in-angualr-6/53035414#53035414

Answer (score 2):

If you get all the comments in the response then you can use `comments.length`

```
<span class="comments_count">{{comments.length}}</span>
```

But the best practice is to get it from the API side. Add one more field in your API response for comment count.

Comment: What are you using in the backend? Is it node.js or any other! If yes then provide your backend API code which returns above data.

Comment: I I got it , everything works as expected , thanks alot , if u dont mind check my other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53033868/how-to-format-dates-in-angualr-6/53035414#53035414

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

While getting comments data from server , You have to return total number of comments along with the new data.

Once you call service you can add data in one array.
and set total count in one variable.

> Note:
>   You have to read count from sever and return result in same API or service

Answer (score 1):

Update your API and get comments count using API and show your comment count.

Answer (score 0):

Such counter must be on the server side.

For example, post has 10000 comments.

1 request will not fetch them all, only a portion (page).

And it's not good to get them all only to find out a count.

So the response should contain a 'count' field.